# Mariadb query optimization - Procedure

Tags: mysql, optimization, mariadb, query

I have a complicated procedure and I have 200 clients. When these 200 clients run the procedure simultaneously, the CPU value suddenly increases to 70%. Then it's 6% again. How can I optimize these queries?

My tables:

```
persons table 4000 rows MyIsam (only select)
person_time table 600 rows MyIsam (only select)
notify_proc table 108,000 rows InnoDb (select and insert ) (Inserting 10000 records per day)
person_proc table 80,000 rows InnoDb (select and insert ) (Inserting 8000 records per day)
comp_way table 4000 rows MyIsam (only select)
excuse_proc is generally empty (only select)
photo table is generally empty (only select)
```

My Proc:
input carid

```sql
BEGIN
SELECT ss.car_route 
from persons p
inner join person_time ss on ss.comp_id =p.comp_id  
                         and ss.start_time<=DATE_FORMAT(CURTIME(),'%H:%i')  
                         AND  ss.finish_time>= date_format(curtime() ,'%H:%i') 
                         AND ss.car_id=carid
                         and ss.day_ like concat('%',(select WEEKDAY(now())+1),'%') 
where (p.car_id=carid or p.back_car_id=carid ) 
LIMIT 1 
into @route;

select sf.stop_hiz 
from car_comp sf 
inner join cars s on s.comp_id = sf.id 
                 and s.id=carid
into @hiz_stat;

if @route = 1 THEN

    select  ss.start_time,ss.finish_time ,p.id,p.name,r.photo, pp.status_ ,pp.time_per,ss.car_route,
            ifnull(bh.id,0) AS called,
            ifnull(mh.excuse_id,0) AS excuse_id,
            ifnull(p.latitude_leave,0) AS latitude_leave,
            ifnull(p.longitude_leave,0) AS longitude_leave,
            ifnull(p.latitude_take,0) AS latitude_take,
            ifnull(p.longitude_take,0) AS longitude_take,
            case when (ifnull(p.call_notify,0)=1 or ifnull(p.sms_notify,0)=1) then 1 else 0 end AS call_notify ,
            ifnull(p.row_num,0) AS row_num,
            ifnull(p.take_phone,0) AS take_phone,
            ifnull(p.leave_phone,0) AS leave_phone,
            ifnull(p.back_row_num,0) AS back_row_num,
            ifnull(ROUND(p.take_notify_meter/2),0) AS take_notify_meter,
            ifnull(ROUND(p.leave_notify_meter/2),0) AS leave_notify_meter,
            ifnull(p.latitude_notify_take,0) AS latitude_notify_take,
            ifnull(p.longitude_notify_take,0) AS longitude_notify_take,
            ifnull(p.latitude_notify_leave,0) AS latitude_notify_leave,
            ifnull(p.longitude_notify_leave,0) AS longitude_notify_leave,
            call_minute,
            ifnull(ok.longi,0) as comp_longitude,
            ifnull(ok.lati,0) as comp_latitude
    from persons p
    inner join person_time ss on ss.comp_id =p.comp_id 
                             and p.car_id=ss.car_id
                             and ss.start_time<=DATE_FORMAT(CURTIME(),'%H:%i')  
                             AND  ss.finish_time>= date_format(curtime() ,'%H:%i')
                             and ss.day_ like concat('%',(select WEEKDAY(now())+1),'%')
    LEFT JOIN notify_proc bh ON bh.table_id=p.id 
                             AND bh.car_route=@route
                             and bh.table_name='person' 
                             AND bh.notification_=4 
                             AND bh.car_id=p.car_id 
                             and date_format(bh.date_,'%Y.%m.%d')=date_format(CURDATE(),'%Y.%m.%d')
    left join  person_proc oh on  pp.person_id=p.id
                              and pp.car_id=p.car_id
                              and date_format(pp.time_per,'%H:%i') >=ss.start_time
                              and date_format(pp.time_per,'%H:%i') <=ss.finish_time
                              AND pp.car_route= @route
                              and pp.id in( select max(id) 
                                            from person_proc
                                            where date_format(time_per,'%Y.%m.%d')=date_format(CURDATE(),'%Y.%m.%d') 
                                              and car_id = carid
                                            GROUP by person_id  )
    left join comp_way ok on p.comp_id = ok.id 
                          and p.car_id=carid
    left join excuse_proc ep on mh.person_id=p.id 
                             and date_format(mh.time_per,'%Y.%m.%d') = date_format(CURDATE(),'%Y.%m.%d') 
                             and (mh.car_route=ss.car_route)
    left join photo p on r.person_id = p.id 
                      and r.table_name = 'person'
    where (ss.car_route=p.car_u_route or p.car_u_route=3) 
      and p.car_id = carid and p.active_=1
      AND p.work_time=ss.work_time
      and @hiz_stat = 0;

else

    select  ss.start_time,ss.finish_time ,p.id,p.name,r.photo, pp.status_ ,pp.time_per,ss.car_route,
            ifnull(bh.id,0) AS called,
            ifnull(mh.excuse_id,0) AS excuse_id,
            ifnull(p.latitude_leave,0) AS latitude_leave,
            ifnull(p.longitude_leave,0) AS longitude_leave,
            ifnull(p.latitude_take,0) AS latitude_take,
            ifnull(p.longitude_take,0) AS longitude_take,
            case when (ifnull(p.call_notify,0)=1 or ifnull(p.sms_notify,0)=1) 
                 then 1 
                 else 0 end AS call_notify ,
            ifnull(p.row_num,0) AS row_num,
            ifnull(p.take_phone,0) AS take_phone,
            ifnull(p.leave_phone,0) AS leave_phone,
            ifnull(p.back_row_num,0) AS back_row_num,
            ifnull(ROUND(p.take_notify_meter/2),0) AS take_notify_meter,
            ifnull(ROUND(p.leave_notify_meter/2),0) AS leave_notify_meter,
            ifnull(p.latitude_notify_take,0) AS latitude_notify_take,
            ifnull(p.longitude_notify_take,0) AS longitude_notify_take,
            ifnull(p.latitude_notify_leave,0) AS latitude_notify_leave,
            ifnull(p.longitude_notify_leave,0) AS longitude_notify_leave,
            call_minute,
            ifnull(ok.longi,0) as comp_longitude,
            ifnull(ok.lati,0) as comp_latitude
    from persons p
    inner join person_time ss on ss.comp_id =p.comp_id 
                              and p.back_car_id=ss.car_id
                              and ss.start_time<=DATE_FORMAT(CURTIME(),'%H:%i')  
                              AND  ss.finish_time>= date_format(curtime() ,'%H:%i')
                              and ss.day_ like concat('%',(select WEEKDAY(now())+1),'%')
    LEFT JOIN notify_proc bh ON bh.table_id=p.id 
                             AND bh.car_route=@route
                             and bh.table_name='person' 
                             AND bh.notification_=4 
                             AND bh.car_id=p.back_car_id 
                             and date_format(bh.date_,'%Y.%m.%d')=date_format(CURDATE(),'%Y.%m.%d')
    left join  person_proc oh on  pp.person_id=p.id
                              and pp.car_id=p.back_car_id and pp.car_route=2
                              and date_format(pp.time_per,'%H:%i') >=ss.start_time
                              and date_format(pp.time_per,'%H:%i') <=ss.finish_time
                              AND pp.car_route= @route
                              and pp.id in( select max(id) 
                                            from person_proc
                                            where date_format(time_per,'%Y.%m.%d')=date_format(CURDATE(),'%Y.%m.%d') 
                                              and car_id = carid
                                            GROUP by person_id )
    left join comp_way ok on p.comp_id = ok.id 
                          and p.car_id=carid
    left join excuse_proc ep on mh.person_id=p.id 
                             and date_format(mh.time_per,'%Y.%m.%d') = date_format(CURDATE(),'%Y.%m.%d') 
                             and (mh.car_route=ss.car_route)
    left join photo p on r.person_id = p.id 
                      and r.table_name = 'person'
    where (ss.car_route=p.car_u_route or p.car_u_route=3) 
      and p.back_car_id = carid 
      and p.active_=1
      AND p.work_time=ss.work_time
      and @hiz_stat = 0;

END IF;

end
```

Comment: I think the  starting of the sp is missing.

Comment: Note: when you combine both MyISAM and Innodb then it locks the table. Try converting to Innodb and check, If it works then move to production.

Comment: Oh sorry. I updated my proc. @James

Comment: The system is currently running. I don't have a chance to test it. I can switch directly. But if it gets worse, how can I get it back? @James

Comment: Remove `and @hiz_stat = 0` from both queries and add it to `if @route = 1`... at least.

Comment: Try to avoid fields calculations in conditions, all calculations must be performed with runtime constants (for example, `and date_format(bh.date_,'%Y.%m.%d')=date_format(CURDATE(),'%Y.%m.%d')` must be replaced with something like `and bh.date_ >= CURDATE() and bh.date_ < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY` if bh.date_ has datetime/timestamp datatype).

Comment: If route = 2 and hiz_stat = 1, the procedure should not run. @Akina

Comment: `date(bh.date_)=curdate()` Will it work? How does it affect performance? @Akina

Comment: *`date(bh.date_)=curdate()` Will it work?* I don't know - you have not specified its datatype. If it is DATE, then will, if DATETIME/TIMESTAMP with non-zero time part then will not... *If route = 2 and hiz_stat = 1, the procedure should not run* But if `hiz_stat = 1` then your long query (in IF or ELSE, dependent by route value) will be at least parsed... whereas you may check previously and do not parse at all in that case.

Comment: That's great. It worked. @Akina

Comment: It rises momentarily again, but the highest is 30%. Do you have any other suggestions? @Akina

Comment: Summarize (or highlight) the difference(s) between the two sides of the IF.  The code looks very similar.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Those would have forestalled at least one comment, perhaps more.

Comment: Any function (eg, `DATE()`) prevents index usage.  Change to `bh.date_ >= curdate()` (unless the date can be some time in the future).

Comment: There is a `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY`; do you care which 'route' you get from the first query?

Comment: `OR` is bad for performance; why do you have `(p.car_id=carid  or  p.back_car_id=carid )`?